# I have a Approval workflow.I need to show pending workflows on the home page it should have people who need to approve

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, development, client-object-model, jquery

I need to create a Dashboard kind of thing on a page to display approval process status of a workflow for a document, who need to approve and what is need to be approved and due date and also link to approve for approvers list. Is this requirement achievable for a Document set content type and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with a view on your tasks list with a filter of `Assigned To is equal to [Me] and Percent Complete is less than 1` and any columns you desire.

Then on your home page, you add in an App Part of your task list and configure it to show this view, setting the title of the app part to be My Pending Tasks.

Comment: Thank you i thought we need some custom development you made it so easy thank you.